# Navigator Key is not Initialised When Waking the App From Call Kit

Tags: flutter, dart, sip, voip, callkit

I have integrated VoIP calls into my Flutter app using [sip_ua](https://pub.dev/packages/sip_ua) package and I have integrated [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming).

### Flow

#### Listening to Call State Changes from SIPHelper

- On receiving the notification in the terminated state, the `SIPController` is initialized and the user is registered on the SIP server.
- On accepting the incoming call, the `Call Screen` is pushed.

#### Listening to FlutterCallKitIncoming Events

- When the User accepts the incoming call from notification in the `terminated` state, it triggers the `Call Accept` event, and that tries to push the `Call Screen` if the `navigatorKey` is not null.

#### Handling Background Messages

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  NotificationService firebaseService = NotificationService();

  await firebaseService.configureFirebaseMessaging();

  crashlyticsSetup();

  await initUserAuthentication();
  // Initialising the SIP Controller
  await initSIP();
}
```

### The Problem

When the `FlutterCallKitIncoming` triggers the call accept event, the flutter's widget tree has not been rendered yet and the `navigatorKey` is null.

### My Query

I'm wondering if a change in flow in handling the `SIPController` initialization or the Screen push can help me get around this issue.